# How am I not using semicolons properly (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm taking Udacity's intro to JS course and I'm baffled by this tutorial on semicolons!

Here is the question:

> Directions:
>   Define two variables called thingOne and thingTwo and assign them values. Print the values of both variables in one console.log 
>   statement using concatenation. For example,
>
> ```
> red blue
> ```
>
> where "red" is the value of thingOne and "blue" is the value of 
>   thingTwo. Don't forget to use semicolons!

I've tried pretty much every variation and I keep getting the answer wrong. I receive this message:

> What Went Well
>
> - Your code should have a variable thingOne
> - Your code should have a variable thingTwo
> - Your code should only have one console.log statement
> - Your code should print out the values of thingOne and thingTwo using concatenation
>
> What Went Wrong
>
> - Your code is missing semicolons at the end of each line

Here is my answer:

```
var thingOne = "red";
var thingTwo = " blue";
console.log(thingOne + thingTwo);
```

I've also tried:

```
var thingOne = "red"; var thingTwo = " blue";
console.log(thingOne + thingTwo);
```

I've also tried both combinations of these wherein the console.log statement does NOT have a semicolon at the end...just to see if that was the problem.

None of these is passing the test.

Is this their error or am I missing something?
Sorry for the absurdly simple question. I just want to make sure I'm learning JS properly. Thanks

Comment: Your problem are not semicolons but a missing space in your console.log output

Comment: Do you mean the space between the two variables? Because I input thingTwo as " blue". I also tried concatenating "red" + " " + "blue". Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding you. Thanks!

Comment: your code looks fine to me, and certainly not missing any semicolons - seems like a bug in Udacity

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is this:

```
var thingOne = "red";
var thingTwo = "blue";
console.log (thingOne + " " + thingTwo);
```

https://repl.it/@meghann/Programming-Quiz-Semicolons-2-8

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run and check your code on browser developer console like this:
[image]

And yes both of your **codes are working** perfectly  fine.

Keyboard **shortcuts to open developer console on chrome** are as follows:

On **Windows** and **Linux**: `Ctrl + Shift + J`.

On **Mac**: `Cmd + Option + J`.

Answer (score -2):

```
var thingOne = "red";//" "==> space
var thingTwo = " blue";//" "==> space
console.log(thingOne + thingTwo);//" "==> space
```

you have space after the line's semicolon, and they need ";" at the end. just a bug

EDIT : for some reason I'm getting downvotes even though that's what happened, it happened to me and i removed the spaces after each semicolon and it got passed.